# Using percentage `width:100%` considering elements `float:left`

Tags: html, css, layout, width, css-float

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/5jJg3/16/) and it got an HTML `img#logo-image`, on some occasions it will not be displayed, `display:none`.

The problem is that the entire `div#menu-title` should fit the width of the page.
I tried putting `width:100%`, but when the `img#logo-imag`" is displayed it breaks the line being below the `img#logo-image`.

The `width:100%` does not work with elements `float:left`

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to float an element which is 100% width.  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of float?

Comment: I floated the element so that it can be on the left.

But have some pages where you will not see, and I need the right elements to fit the page size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just unfloat the menu-title div and remove the width.. it will automatically be 100% of the header then..  and if the image is present it will adjust the `ul#menu` list to make room for it, which is a natural behaviour

if you want the menu-list to really only take the available width (say for a background color or something then you can add `overflow: hidden;` to `ul#menu` - though I don't see a need for that in your example code

here's a simplified version of your Fiddle - hover on the header to make the image disappear and see the `ul#menu` adjust to suit

### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/HMNMR/)

Answer (score 2):

You have both logo-image and menu-title floating left.  Since they arent really in separate divs, they are all part of the same div, they appear next to each other.  On top of that, you set the menu-title to be 760, which isn't the width of the page.  At least that what it looks like you did.  Do not use width 100% because resizing the page will shrink that menu title.

You really just have to play around with the divs, but i would say that separating those two divs would make you be able to stack them on top or below each other.

And in using Chrome's inspect element feature, I don't see a display:none for the image's css. I don't know why that would do that.

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand. My question is: with two divs side by side float:left when disappear the first div, display:none the second ally to fill the whole page, something like width:100%

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure of what you are trying to accomplish since making the div#menu-title width: 100% doesn't leave any room for anything else on the same row.

Why not let them both be inline and let the widths be whatever they need to be?

Anyway, I have a guess at what you want. You want those two elements to behave as being in a table, inside a table row, and each in a table-cell so that the image takes a maximum width, and the div#menu-title taking all of the rest of the place. In that case put them in a table, or use display: table-cell for the image and the div and fiddle around with that.

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand.
My question is: with two divs side by side `float:left` when disappear  the first div, `display:none` the second ally to fill the whole page, something like `width:100%`

Comment: Oh i think i know what you are asking.  You want the second div to fill the whole page when the first div's display becomes `none`, correct?  If that's the case, then make the width when the div becomes invisible to 0px.  By the way, a better way to make it disappear is to set `visibility:hidden`

Comment: But make the width 0px and the padding and margins and everything 0px